# How do I reactivate Swype on a Motorola Atrix HD?

Tags: swype, motorola-atrix-hd

I disabled Swype on my Motorola Atrix HD. How can I get it to reactivate after turning it back on?

I went into 'Language & Input' and deselected it, but when I took the same path to turn it back on, it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the Default keyboard?

[image]